# Set socket.io server side cookie during handshake

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io

Is there a way to set a `httpOnly` cookie during the initial handshake (websockets or longpolling) with socket.io on the server side?

I can read cookies from the client easily by using `socket.request.headers.cookie` but can't find a way to set a cookie on the response.

Comment: I need the cookie to be httpOnly so can’t set it on the client via an event. Not sure what you first comment mean, it’s pretty standard to set a cookie on a response.

Comment: Could this be of any use to you? https://gist.github.com/jfromaniello/4087861